# Abstract Factory Pattern - dependency between concrete products

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, language-agnostic, factory-pattern

Please read the code below, the questions are at the end.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Graphics
{
    public interface IGraphicsFactory
    {
        ICanvas CreateCanvas();
        Square CreateSquare();
        ComposedShape CreateComposedShape();
    }

    public class SimpleGraphicsFactory : IGraphicsFactory
    {
        public Square CreateSquare()
        {
            return new SimpleImpl.SimpleSquare();
        }

        public ComposedShape CreateComposedShape()
        {
            return new SimpleImpl.SimpleComposedShape();
        }

        public ICanvas CreateCanvas()
        {
            return new SimpleImpl.SimpleCanvas();
        }
    }

    public interface ICanvas
    {
        void AddShape(ShapeBase shape);
        void Render();
    }

    public abstract class ShapeBase
    {
        public abstract void Paint(ICanvas canvas);
    }

    public abstract class Square : ShapeBase
    {
        public int size;
    }

    public abstract class ComposedShape : ShapeBase
    {
        public int size;
        public ShapeBase InternalShape1 { get; set; }
        public ShapeBase InternalShape2 { get; set; }
    }
}


namespace Graphics.SimpleImpl
{
    internal class SimpleSquare : Graphics.Square
    {
        public void Init()
        {
            // do something really important
        }

        public override void Paint(ICanvas canvas)
        {
            Init();

            //?? how to avoid the type cast? (and I want to keep the DrawLine out of the ICanvas interface)
            SimpleCanvas scanvas = (canvas as SimpleCanvas);
            scanvas.DrawLine();
            scanvas.DrawLine();
            scanvas.DrawLine();
            scanvas.DrawLine();
        }
    }

    internal class SimpleComposedShape : Graphics.ComposedShape
    {
        public void Init()
        {
            //?? how can I call `InternalShape1.Init', preferably without type casts? (and I want to keep `Init` out of the `ShapeBase` class)
            // this.InternalShape1.Init();
            // this.InternalShape2.Init();
        }

        public override void Paint(ICanvas canvas)
        {
            Init();
            // TODO: draw the thing
        }
    }

    internal class SimpleCanvas : Graphics.ICanvas
    {
        List<ShapeBase> shapes = new List<ShapeBase>();

        public void AddShape(ShapeBase shape)
        {
            shapes.Add(shape);
        }

        public void Render()
        {
            foreach (ShapeBase s in shapes)
            {
                s.Paint(this);
            }
        }


        public void DrawLine()
        {
        }
    }
}


namespace Test
{
    using Graphics;
    class TestSimpleGraphics
    {
        static void Test1()
        {
            IGraphicsFactory fact = new SimpleGraphicsFactory();
            ICanvas canvas = fact.CreateCanvas();

            Square sq1 = fact.CreateSquare();
            Square sq2 = fact.CreateSquare();
            ComposedShape cs = fact.CreateComposedShape();
            cs.InternalShape1 = sq1;
            cs.InternalShape2 = sq2;

            canvas.AddShape(cs);
            canvas.Paint();
        }
    }
}
```

1. Is my abstract factory pattern implementation correct?
2. Inside `SimpleSquare.Paint`: it is possible to avoid the type cast? (and I want to keep the `DrawLine` out of the `ICanvas` interface)
3. Inside `SimpleComposedShape.Init`: how can I call `InternalShape.Init`, preferably without type casts? (and I want to keep `Init` out of the `ShapeBase` class)

Comment: This is too much code to address #1, but for #2: you cannot avoid the cast without putting it in that interface (or a different one) or perhaps using a generic somewhere. Also, you need to check for null after the cast. For #3, I'd just add it to the base class or use a generic ComposedShape<T> where T : ShapeBase.

Comment: If you have a factory for `ICanvas` implementations, I would name it `CanvasFactory`. Also, what is your `ICanvas` supposed to represent or abstract? I don't understand its purpose. When should `AddShape` be called? Why does a canvas contain a list of shapes? What should happen inside `ShapeBase.Paint`? Is a `ICanvas` implementation responsible for drawing graphics primitives? In that case, why shouldn't it provide public methods for that?

Comment: @Groo: my graphics model is meant to be something like a "retained mode" graphics library, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retained_mode. So, think of the canvas like something similar to the DOM of the browser. It doesn't provide primitives to draw lines or rectangles, just to add objects into it, and the objects are rendered internally. The `ShapeBase.Paint` is abstract so it can't have a body. And this whole thing is just an equivalent model of something else I'm working on, which has completely different semantics, probably that's why the sample code it's not the best.

Comment: Yes, I understand that you want to store the DOM, but the point is that a concrete `ICanvas` should store primitive shapes which are **aware** of its actual implementation (for example, a `SimpleSquare` should have a `Paint(SimpleCanvas)` method, not a `Paint(ICanvas)` method).

Comment: In the interest of KISS, do you really have multiple families of implementations?  ARe you really going to have a set of SimpleXXX classes and also a sent of ComplexXxx classes and a MediocreXxx classes?  Don't over-complicate if you don't need it.

Comment: @tcarvin, yes, there will be multiple families of objects, and I want the user to be able to switch very easy between these families of objects (changing a single line of code).

Comment: @tcarvin: I didn't add the also the code for ComplexXxx, and MediocreXxx in order to keep the code shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - I think your `SimpleGraphicsFactory` is indeed a good example of an Abstract Factory.

2 - It is completely appropriate that `SimpleSquare` casts to `SimpleCanvas` because they are both part of the same "family", created by the same concrete factory.  Recall the definition of Abstract Factory (emphasis is mine):

> Provide an interface for creating families of *related or dependent*
>   objects without specifying their concrete classes.

The implication of this design pattern is that the classes created by it can assume / require they are being used with classes from the same family.

To use another example from the .NET world, the `System.Data` namespaces acts in a similar way.   Objects from the `System.Data.Sql` namespaces will not work with objects from System.Data.Oracle.  You cannot pass a `SqlParameter` where an `OracleParameter` is expected.  You select the family and stay within the family.

3 -   I cannot tell what you are trying to do, you;ll need to comment with details and I'll revies my answer to address.  I would expect a `ComposedShape` to have a method `Add(Shape s)` that lets the caller add multiple shapes to the composite (container).  But perhaps I misunderstand.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I wasn't sure that my implementation is correct, because of the casts required in the concrete classes. These casts feel somehow natural, but it will be nice to avoid them, and I wanted to know if this is also possible.

I modified the code example to be a little bit more clear; in my example, the `ComposedShape` is simpler than you expected, it contains just two different shapes, which are specified at runtime. The requirement, in my case, is that both of the internal shapes have to be completely initialized before calling `Paint`.

Comment: I don't agree that these casts are "completely appropriate". I've rarely seen a cast which doesn't indicate a problem in OOP implementation, and in this case the solutions are obvious: you either want to have a concrete `SimpleCanvas` parameter in `SimpleSquare.Paint`, or you need to make this method public.

Comment: It is tough when OP asks multiple questions in a single post.  I did not want to dissect the methods too much.  The theme (and title) of the question was on having dependencies between objects created in the Abstract Factory pattern.  And to that I say that *yes* you can.  It is what it is designed for.  To get down to the nitty-gritty, I don't understand why `Paint` would be a family-specific method so I suspect there are other problems in the design.

Comment: And from looking at the edits and comments on the original question, the code sample is just a sample for discussion sake and may not be worth dissecting too much.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your intentions right, you are trying to mimic the functionality of the `System.Drawing.Graphics` class (or HTML `<canvas>`, for example).

If that's correct, I would give following suggestions:

1. Rename `IGraphicsFactory` to `ICanvasFactory` and let it create only concrete `ICanvas` implementations. Remove the `CreateSquare` and other methods, because you don't have to create shapes through a factory (it's only important that your Shapes are passed a concrete `ICanvas` implementation).
2. The `ICanvas` interface represents a canvas which can draw primitive shapes (lines, circles, filled areas, etc.). This means that you should expose public methods which will allow callers to create these primitives. `Graphics` also provides various transformation capabilities, but this may be an overkill right now:

   ```
   interface ICanvas
   {
        void Clear();
        void DrawLine(Point from, Point to, Pen pen);
        void DrawCircle(Point center, Double radius, Pen pen);
        void Paint();
        /* and stuff like that */
   }
   ```
3. A `Canvas` should not contain a list of `Shapes`, but rather a list of primitives. E.g., when you call the `ICanvas.DrawLine(...)` method, it should create an instance of a `Line` primitive and store it in the internal list.

   The functionality of these primitive classes will depend on the actual implementation of your `ICanvas` (does it paint to a Bitmap, or to a printer, etc.). You will also have some hidden, implementation-dependent data (I will use a `byte[]`, pretending it stores an 8-bit bitmap of some sort):

   ```
   class BitmapCanvas : ICanvas
   {
       private readonly byte[] _bitmapData;
       private readonly List<IBitmapShape> _primitives;

       public BitmapCanvas(int width, int height)
       {
           _bitmapData = new byte[width * height];
           _primitives = new List<IPrimitiveShape>();
       }

       public void DrawLine(...) 
       {
           // different implementations will handle this part differently.
           _primitives.Add(new BitmapLine(_bitmapData, from, to, pen));
       }

       public void Paint()
       {
           Clear(_bitmapData);
           foreach (var shape in _primitives)
               shape.Draw();
       }
   }
   ```
4. Concrete primitive classes would then handle this internal logic:

   ```
   class BitmapLine : IBitmapShape
   {
       public void Draw()
       {
           // write to the underlying byte array
       }
   }
   ```
5. Since `ICanvas` implementation will not draw actual shapes, you don't need the `ShapeBase` class. You will, however, need an analogue class for drawing graphic primitives  (called `IBitmapShape` above).

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't address my questions at all. The example is just an equivalent model of something else I'm working on, which has completely different semantics, so probably that's you feel that I want something else.

Comment: I thought I answered them implicitly, but if you want explicit answers, here they go: 1. Correct factory implementation? Yes and no. Needs to be renamed according to .NET naming conventions, and needs to lose methods which don't belong there. 2. Cast inside `SimpleSquare.Paint`: yes, you need to make the method public, because canvas abstractions are supposed to abstract these methods for other classes (and allow other classes to call them - check how `System.Drawing.Graphics` and HTML `canvas` work. 3. The `Init` method should be removed and done inside the `Shape` constructor.

Comment: The thing is that I don't want to implement a graphics system at all, but something else. So to give you another example, suppose that I want to implement a database access library. Then `ICanvas` is something like `ISqlConnection`, `ICanvas.Render` is like `ISqlConnection.Execute`, `ShapeBase` is `SqlCommand`, `SquareShape` is `SelectCommand`, `SimpleCanvas` can be `MySqlConnection`. So, even if my example models do not make sens in real world, I can't do such big changes as you proposed.

Comment: First of all, there is no such thing as `ISqlConnection`. There is an `IDbConnection` and a concrete `SqlConnection`. And this brings us exactly to what I am talking about: an `SqlCommand` [takes a concrete `SqlConnection` in its constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/877h0y3a.aspx), not just an arbitrary `IDbConnection`. That's why your `SimpleSquare` needs to take a concrete `SimpleCanvas` (note the `Simple` - `Sql` prefix analogy) and throw away the `ICanvas` interface, removing the need for casting.

Comment: `ShapeBase.Paint(ICanvas)` method is redundant, as well as that whole abstract class. I would replace `ShapeBase` with `interface ISimpleShape { void Paint(ISimpleCanvas); }` for all *simple shapes* and get rid of the `ShapeBase` class completely (it's simply not something you need to impose on all `ICanvas` implentations).

Comment: `SqlCommand` does indeed have a method that takes a generic `IDbConnection`, and that is the explicit implementation of `IDbCommand.Connection`.  And within it, it certainly casts from the generic `IDbConnection` to an `SqlConnection`.  **Both** approaches are present and appropriate, and are not mutually exclusive.  The generic version supports the case where the caller does not want to be subclass aware.  The specific version is for when the caller knows / desires a specific family.

Comment: @tcarvin: you are completely missing my point, and doing so just for the sake of making your own answer make sense. Yes, that property certainly casts internally, and happily throws run-time errors for wrong implementations. There are many explicit interface implementations like this in BCL, which should be used mostly for dirty hacks or by the BCL internally. From OOP point of view (and OP's question is about design patterns), it's wrong. The funniest thing of all is, OP actually understands that casts are a sign of wrong design, but you still convinced her/him that it's somehow ok to do it.

Comment: @tcarvin: to summarize: yes, you will find an explicit implementation now and then which will obviously be weakly typed, but to create a class hierarchy from scratch, which will force you to cast in non-explicit interface implementations is plain wrong and the design needs to be refactored. I have described those issues, I have shown a proper OOP example, and you and OP are completely ignoring it. The solution removes the need for casting and is better from OOP perspective, and you are arguing that casting will also work "appropriately". Nope, it's just unnecessary.

Comment: We shall have to agree to disagree.  Explicit interface implementations are not hack.  They is perfectly valid technique often seen when creating extensible frameworks.

Comment: You removed the "Abstract Factory", which was central to the OP question.

Comment: @tcarvin: oh, come on. Read the answer more carefully then. Point 1. to be precise. There is nothing "central" about that part of the question, as it's mostly correct (naming conventions don't bother me that much), and I haven't removed it. The casting is what is incorrect and what you happily choose to ignore.

Comment: We only know what the OP posted, so I think you presumed too much when you wrote "Remove the CreateSquare and other methods, because you don't have to create shapes through a factory".  That is only true if the Shapes are not dependent from Canvas.  If a `VectorCanvas` can only act upon `VectorShape` and a `BitmapCanvas` can only work with a `BitmpaShape` then it is appropriate to use the `Abstract Factory` pattern as defined by the GoF.

Comment: Note the last two Comments to the OP question.  I sought clarification  on this very thing.